# Не могу получить данные по SOAP Perl-ом (SOAP::Lite)

Tags: perl, soap

Perl почти не знаю, SOAP тоже так себе. Попросили помочь, приходится разбираться.
Пытаюсь вот таким простейшим кодом:

```
using strict;
using SOAP;
my $soap = SOAP::Lite->new(proxy => 
'http://86.57.245.235/TimeTable/Service.asmx');
$soap->service('http://86.57.245.235/TimeTable/Service.asmx?WSDL');
$soap->ns('http://webservices.belavia.by/');
my $retval = $soap->GetAirportsList('RU');
```

получить данные.
WSDL лежит здесь - http://86.57.245.235/TimeTable/Service.asmx?WSDL.
Самый ответственный кусок WSDL привожу тут:

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="http://webservices.belavia.by/" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://webservices.belavia.by/">
.......
<wsdl:binding name="OnlineTimeTableSoap" type="tns:OnlineTimeTableSoap">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="GetTimeTable">...</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetAirportsList">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://webservices.belavia.by/GetAirportsList" style="document"/>
```

В отладчике видно, что WSDL схема грузится, в ней видны объект и нужные методы, но в ответ приходит такое описание ошибки:

```
"Сервер не распознал значение заголовка HTTP SOAPAction:http://webservices.belavia.by/#GetAirportsList."
```

Т.е., что-то я делаю не так. Вопрос - что?

Comment: Ну, вот прямо сейчас вообще так: `Service description 'http://86.57.245.235/TimeTable/Service.asmx?WSDL' can't be loaded: 503 Service Unavailable`

Comment: Периодически бывает. Он у них не стабильно как-то работает.

Comment: Разобрался.
В модуле Lite.pm поле SOAPAction формируется таким образом 
     _on_action    => sub { sprintf '"%s#%s"', shift || '', shift },

Comment: Первый shift это namespace, второй methodName.
Накой черт вставляется этот символ, а это вроде бы якорь в URL, мне не ясно. И дело в том, что не все SOAP сервера ведут себя лояльно по отношению к этому символу. Некоторые проглатывают, а некоторые (как указанный в изначальном вопросе) матюгаются.